# Personal access code on sheet of paper for SurveyMonkey

Tags: surveymonkey

Is it possible to make invitations on a sheet of paper with a personal access code for an online survey/evaluation on https://www.surveymonkey.com/ in free plan?

If not are there other online services which can do this?

The background is that I want to create an online evaluation for a small course I teach. To make it anonymous I want to hand out (randomly) to each participant a sheet of paper with a personal authentication code for the survey (and the URL of the evaluation of course).

Comment: If it's anonymous, you don't need personal access codes. You should just have one.

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise That's to make sure that everybody does the survey just *once*.

Comment: So your main concern is to only allow people to take the survey once, as opposed to needing survey codes?

Comment: Not only: It should be anonymous and it should be clear to the participants that it is truly anonymous. It should be ensured that every person can to the survey just once and no other persons can to it.

Comment: You can manually create _a unique collector per student_ and set a password for it, then instead of just printing the access code, print both web link and password and hand them out randomly. The problem is, for creating unlimited collectors, you need a _pro account_. This link may help you [Can I create a unique login and password for each survey respondent?](http://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/Can-I-create-a-unique-login-and-password-for-each-survey-participant)

Answer (score 2):

This can most likely be achieved by using a combination of Gmail and SurveyMonkey although there would be a manual process involved.

Open a gmail account with a generic name such as mystudentsurveys@gmail.com.

Use [SurveyMonkey's Email Invitation collector](http://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/How-do-I-send-a-survey-through-SurveyMonkey-s-Email-Invitation-Collector) to generate a list of survey URLs with custom email addresses such as:

mystudentsurveys+0001@gmail.com
mystudentsurveys+0002@gmail.com
mystudentsurveys+0003@gmail.com
mystudentsurveys+0004@gmail.com

All the links will be delivered to your gmail account where you can copy/paste/print/randomly assign them to participants.

**Additional**

SurveyMonkey don't like + symbols or %2B URLEncoded + symbols in email addresses.

Use Gmail's other little-abused fact that they don't process periods (.) at all so signing up the following email addresses will result in survey invitations landing in the same inbox.

m.ystudentsurveys@gmail.com
my.studentsurveys@gmail.com
mys.tudentsurveys@gmail.com
myst.udentsurveys@gmail.com

Comment: Do I own automatically the adresses of the form mystudentsurveys+xyzw@gmail.com (x,y,z,w integers) which point to mystudentsurveys@gmail.com, if I create a gmail adress mystudentsurveys@gmail.com? If so, how is this feature called is this unique to gmail?

Comment: Cannot comment on other providers but with gmail you can alias your mailbox by appending +anything and it'll still be a valid address. Caveat: some automatic validation won't allow plus characters, although I believe it is RFC compliant.

Comment: I tested it but the problem is that surveyMonkey doesn't seem to allow e-mail addresses that contain `+` characters.

Comment: ok, here's an outside the box solution: Gmail doesn't recognize periods as characters in addresses so you could probably use m.ystudentsurveys@gmail.com, my.studentsurveys@gmail.com, mys.tudentsurveys@gmail.com etc.  Which is OK if you don't have many students in a class. I'd recommend re-using them if possible or it'd get quite silly.